# React 15 drops input value with empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and trying to render an input of type submit with value="" so that I can then use an image as my submit instead of a button.

My element before render is

```
<input type="submit" value=""/>
```

This worked well in react 0.14, but in react 15.0.2 it will render to

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

dropping value="". This causes the browser to display 'Submit' by default where the input is placed.

How can I achieve the old behaviour in react 15.0.2?

Comment: Why not use a `<button>` and put an image inside of it?

Comment: Why not just use... `<img onClick={this.submitForm()} />` or something? seems easier to me.

Comment: Maybe using a whitespace character like `&nbsp;` as input value is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with the commenters that you should instead use a `<button>`. However, you can probably *hack* it by using an empty string inside, like `value={String.fromCharCode(156)}`.

Comment: Thanks that works. The only problem with the button would be that the enter is not automatically binded to the form submit and I would like to be able to use both the enter and the image button.

Comment: The button will indeed submit the form by default, you just need to handle the form's submit :)